# Programatically updated ListPreferences is not displayed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When the user updates a shared preference through a subclass of `PreferenceActivity` I check whether or not the new value is valid at the given time. If not the value should be changed back in the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method.

This works so far. I set an `OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener`, the method gets called. The user-set value will be overwritten and the new value will be used in the app, however when I open this specific preferences value (in this case a `ListPreference`) again the wrong list item will be selected (the one the user selected, not the one set in the Listener). I tried overwriting the value with both:

```
mPrefs.edit().putString("answers", value.toString()).commit();
mPrefs.edit().putString("answers", value.toString()).apply();
```

Are there additional steps I need to take to update the `ListPreference`? After restarting the `PreferenceActivity` the value will be displayed correctly.

Comment: I've tried to overwrite sharedpreferences but i had to remove it first, commit the remove, and then put it and commit again...

Comment: I just tried this `mPrefs.edit().remove("answers").commit();` with both commit() and apply() without any success.

Comment: have you tried ‘mPrefs.edit().remove("answers").commit();‘ and then ‘mPrefs.edit().putString("answers", value.toString()).commit();‘ ?

Comment: Yes, I did, with the same result. The value is set, but the view not updated.

Comment: Try calling onContentChanged() after commiting the pref change. If that doesn't work, you need to call loadPreferencesFromResource() again after you commit the new preference, but you'll need to figure out how to clear the current preferences from the root first. Don't know how to do that.

Comment: Neither of these solved the issue, but I found a solution that answered the question. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this issue by setting the value manually as described here:

http://liquidlabs.ca/2011/08/25/update-preference-value-without-reloading-preferenceactivity/

Answer (score 1):

```
try to use Override method SharedPreferenceChanged

@Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                String key) {           
            if (key.equals(KEY)) {
                Preference ServicePref = findPreference(key);
                // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value         

                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);                 

            }           
    }
```

Comment: This is what I did, just edited the question to make it more clear